# Efficient subsetting over a list of matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix, fuzzy-logic

I have a list of matrices like this one:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.8  2.0  3.2
[2,]  2.0  3.2  4.4
[3,]  3.2  4.4  5.6

[[2]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] -1.95 1.00 3.95
[2,]  1.00 3.95 6.90
[3,]  3.95 6.90 9.85

[[3]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] -1.1  0.1  1.3
[2,]  0.1  1.3  2.5
[3,]  1.3  2.5  3.7
```

And I want to get a vector with only a specific row and column of every matrix in the list, the rows are chosen by a vector.

I made a code to do this:

```
xmin <- NULL
row <- c(2,3,2)
for(i in 1:3){
  xmin[i] <- lista[[i]][row[i] , 1]
}
```

The problem is that I want to make this selection at the most efficient way and I want to avoid `for` loops and, if its possible, functions like `mapply` and `lapply` because I must call this function millions of times. Timings whit `mapply` are slightly inferior than `for` loop timing, but it isn't sufficiently faster.

Is there any possible way to do this subsetting with R basics selection functions ( `[[`, `[` or `$` operators) ?

Comment: Have you tried `mapply(function(x,y) x[y,1] , lista, row)` or try row/column indexing . `rC <- cbind(row,1); mapply(`[`, lista,lapply(split(rC, row(rC)), t))`

Comment: Another option is `m1 <- do.call(rbind, lista); m1[cbind(row+seq(0,length(lista)*nrow(lista[[1]])-1, by=3),1)]
#[1] 2.00 3.95 0.10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your matrices all have the same dimensions, you can turn them into a 3-dimensional array and use indexing.

```
lst <- list(matrix(1:9, 3, 3), matrix(10:18, 3, 3), matrix(19:27, 3, 3))
arr <- do.call(cbind, lst)
dim(arr) <- c(3, 3, 3)

getl <- function(row, col)
sapply(1:3, function(i) lst[[i]][row[i], col])

geta <- function(row, col)
arr[cbind(row, col, 1:3)]

> system.time(replicate(100000, getl(1, 2)))
   user  system elapsed 
   2.65    0.00    2.65 

> system.time(replicate(100000, geta(1, 2)))
    user  system elapsed 
   0.47    0.00    0.47
```

Comment: This solution works really fine, all my matrices has the same dimension. I have a doubt, the number of matrices that I have in the list is always the same during the execution of the algorithm, but this number is a parameter and I have to work with it so, I must do for my problem: `dim(arr) <- replicate(n_matrices, 3)`  and in the `geta` function: `geta <- function(row, col)
arr[cbind(row, col, 1:n_matrices)]`

Answer (score 2):

I found it worthy to benchmark some alternatives, including akrun's and Hong Ooi's.

1) A "for" loop with a pre-allocated result:

```
ff1 = function(x, vec) 
{
    ans = numeric(length(x))

    for(i in seq_along(x)) ans[i] = x[[i]][vec[i], 1]

    return(ans)
}
```

2) A compiled "for" loop:

```
cmpff1 = compiler::cmpfun(ff1)
```

3) A `mapply`:

```
ff2 = function(x, vec) mapply(function(elt, i) elt[i, 1], x, vec)
```

4) `cbind`ing and use matrix indexing (Hong Ooi):

```
ffHO = function(x, vec) 
        "dim<-"(do.call(cbind, x), 
                c(dim(x[[1]]), length(x)))[cbind(vec, 1, seq_len(length(x)))]
```

5) A modification of the (4), to just add an attribute:

```
ffHO2 = function(x, vec) 
       "dim<-"(unlist(x), 
               c(dim(x[[1]]), length(x)))[cbind(vec, 1, seq_len(length(x)))]
```

And the comparison:

```
myls = replicate(5e4, matrix(runif(100), 10, 10), simplify = FALSE)
vec = sample(1:10, 5e4, T)

ans1 = ff1(myls, vec)
ans2 = cmpff1(myls, vec)
ans3 = ff2(myls, vec)
ans4 = ffHO(myls, vec)
ans5 = ffHO2(myls, vec)

identical(ans1, ans2)
#[1] TRUE
identical(ans1, ans3)
#[1] TRUE
identical(ans1, ans4)
#[1] TRUE
identical(ans1, ans5)
#[1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(ff1(myls, vec), cmpff1(myls, vec), 
                               ff2(myls, vec), ffHO(myls, vec), 
                               ffHO2(myls, vec), times = 15)
#Unit: milliseconds
#              expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
#    ff1(myls, vec) 113.26685 132.36089 138.28047 147.97974 240.7101    15
# cmpff1(myls, vec)  51.23446  55.35398  58.18066  69.07220  82.4652    15
#    ff2(myls, vec) 119.44709 138.54739 145.66654 156.75227 219.9084    15
#   ffHO(myls, vec) 119.57063 130.52029 141.02867 149.21742 174.8242    15
#  ffHO2(myls, vec)  40.69163  41.31125  47.80939  48.55551 118.1069    15
```